# How to get time elapsed from starting date to an end date C#

Tags: c#, datetime, elapsedtime

I'm trying to get the time elapsed from a starting date to an end date in C#

Assuming that my start date is "11/19/2017 05:50 P.M." and the end date is "11/19/2017 05:55 P.M." get the time elapsed, in this case was 5:00 minutes.

But also would like to get for example "5 days and 25 minutes" elapsed

any idea to do this?

Comment: TimeSpan duration = endDate - startDate

Comment: i checked the answer and worked for me, if you want to delete this post is ok.

Comment: You might also consider that "5 days and 25 minutes"  is approximately "5 days". That's the concept for ["time ago"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/calculate-relative-time-in-c-sharp) libraries. But if you do want precise concepts, [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org/) is the thing to use. Where I'm from, some days have 23 hours, some 24, some 25.

Comment: @Jorge If it worked for you, you should upvote it and set it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
TimeSpan span = (EndDateTime - StartDateTime);

String.Format("{0} days, {1} hours, {2} minutes, {3} seconds", 
    span.Days, span.Hours, span.Minutes, span.Seconds);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this. Just subtract the dates and call the method you want

```
 DateTime Date1=new DateTime(2017, 11, 29, 5 + 12, 50, 0);
 DateTime date2 = new DateTime(2017, 11, 29, 5 + 12, 55, 0);
 var diff = (date2 - date1);
```

Then call the method you want from the resulting diff object;

```
double minutesDiff=diff.TotalMinutes;
int days=minutesDiff \(24*60);
int minLeft=  minutesDiff %(24*60);
```

You can finish it from here

Comment: What is the benefit of using your days calculation vs `diff.Days`?